# using require.js to load javascript libraries

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I am trying to have folder structure given [here](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/todo-app/js).

The difference is I am using all latest development  version of these libraries. However, they are not correctly being uploaded, even jquery. I could not understand what by AMD compatible mean.

I simply downloaded those libraries. Does it mean they are not AMD compatible? Is there a separate AMD compatible version of those libraries?. Do we need to use shim config to load non AMD compatible?.

I am afraid to use shim because require.js official documentation says it is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

@kryger's right that jQuery is AMD-compatible and there's nothing wrong with *shimming* non-AMD modules.

AMD-compatible just means that the module adheres to the [AMD specification](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD); hence it exports its functionality.  For example:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore'], function ($, _) {
    // function body
});
```

So in the function body, above:

- you can access jQuery via the `$` argument; but
- underscore doesn't export itself for AMD, so the `_` argument will be `undefined`.

Some AMD-compatible modules (e.g. jQuery) also work 'standalone', such as in an HTML `<script>` tag, where they will export to the global namespace (e.g. `window.$`).

I think jQuery still exports the global `$` when you load it via an AMD loader, so you could just load jQuery once at your entry-point / when it is first needed and always access the global `$` (rather than defining a `$` argument).

Also, if you use jQuery plugins (which modify the global one) it can all get a bit confusing!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any mention of `shim` being "not recommended" in the documentation; I wouldn't be too worried about it. It's a well-tested and increasingly popular way of bridging non-AMD-compliant libraries with RequireJS (previously the only way to do this was was to build a dedicated AMD version wrapped in the define call; that puts extra effort on the library maintainers).

If by "latest development version" you mean jQuery's *Pre-Release Builds*, it looks like it **does** support AMD (have a look at the [pre-release section](http://jquery.com/download/) of the download page, scroll down to very bottom the [source code file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js): you'll see code relating to AMD)

`Backbone` and `underscore` need to be shimmed in any case since they are AMD-agnostic, so there's no escaping from it (these two particular libraries are even used in [shim config option documentation example](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim), so you can just reuse that).